# Изменение размера картинок в директории

Tags: php

Есть папка /var/www/html/image_big/
В ней лежат картинки.
Нужно что бы все скрипт взял картинку изменил ее размеры и скопировал новую в директорию /var/www/html/litle_img/
В PHP.net нашел алгоритм. Картинка сохраняется.

Как можно провести все это через цикл, что бы преобразовать все картинки в заданной директории?

```
$filename = 'data/images/products/1324288902.jpg';

$width = 200;
$height = 200;


header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// получение новых размеров
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
$width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
$height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}
$file = "data/images/new_image.jpg";

$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);


imagejpeg($image_p, $file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `scandir()` вернет массив файлов в данной директории.А дальше `foreach()`